# vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: vue_amap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.service is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Here's the code for my error function. The run-time error message is `service is not a function`:

```js
methods:{
    getAddre(lnglatXY){

        AMap.service('AMap.Geocoder',function() {//回调函数

            var geocoder = new AMap.Geocoder({
            });
            geocoder.getAddress(lnglatXY, function (status, result) {
                if (status === 'complete' && result.info === 'OK') {
                    //获得了有效的地址信息:
                    //即，result.regeocode.formattedAddress
                    // alert(result.regeocode.formattedAddress)
                    // document.getElementById("address").value=result.regeocode.formattedAddress;//将获取 
                       到的地址信息赋值给文本框，保存进数据库
                    this.address = result.regeocode.formattedAddress;
                    alert(this.address)
                } else {
                    //获取地址失败
                    alert('获取地址失败')
                }
            });
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Aiden welcome to stack overflow but please change your code comment to English so everyone can understand ty:)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `AMap` but in the examples it seems to use `AMap.plugin` rather than `AMap.service`: https://lbs.amap.com/api/javascript-api/guide/services/geocoder